# MSBuild Extension Pack

Tags: msbuild, assemblyinfo, msbuildextensionpack

I'm messing around with some TFS build definition files and run into a little problem. I se MSBuild Extension Pack, as explained [here](http://mikefourie.wordpress.com/2009/11/), but for some reason my assemblyInfo.cs files are not checked out from TFS2010. Should this task check out all the specified files and change the assembly version? It changes the version correctly in all the files, however there are no pending changes afterwards. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - No, the files will not automatically be checked out. Use MBEP to checkout the files    - especially if you haven't linked the AssemblyINfo.cs file into each project and have a very large project. Then you'll hit the max 259 characters error :(

```
<MsBuild.ExtensionPack.VisualStudio.TfsSource TaskAction="Checkout" ItemCol="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)" WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionRoot)" Version="2010"/>
```